# How to display videos in Ionic using ion-slide-box

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, ionic-framework

I'm making a small application to display players and their videos. For that I used ion-slide-box with different ion-slides, on each slide I have a different video.

I just have a button to click and then the video is displayed full screen. the problem is that I'm not able to close the video and get back to my application.

You might be wondering why I didn't embeded the videos, I tried to do that but all the videos can play together and this is annoying, I spent two days on how to reslove that, and I didn't find any solution.

here is my code :

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" show-pager="true" ng-if="items" >
  <ion-slide  ng-repeat="i in items"> 

         <div  class="video">
    <img class="full-image" style="height:200px"ng-src="{{i.image}}" />
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I0riVRmp6G0"></a>
</div>
           <h4>{{i.name}}</h4>       

    <p>{{i.age}}</p>
</div> 
  </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
```

Controller :

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items=friends;


      $scope.slideHasChanged = function(index) {

          $scope.items.push("{name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'}");
      }

});

var friends = [
  {name:'John', age:25, image:'http://san.capitalafrique.com/imatin.net/articles/images/lionel-messi.jpg'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, image:'http://www.africatopsports.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Sofiane-feghouli-team-teaser100_v-original-1024x576.jpg'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, image:'http://www.footmercato.net/images/a/feghouli-a-fait-mal-au-barca_123563.jpg'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, image:'http://img.fifa.com/mm/photo/tournament/competition/02/38/72/29/2387229_full-lnd.jpg'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, image:'http://www.parisfans.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Mercato-Le-PSG-voudrait-Xavi-pour-une-saison.jpg'}

];
```

[CODEPEN CODE + DEMO](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/vOXJYx)

Comment: I would look into using a video player plugin for angular. http://www.videogular.com/

Comment: check out all of their examples: http://www.videogular.com/examples/